# Project Entitlements : Devops API not bringing ProjectEntitlements and it shows null

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, devops, entitlements

I am trying to get Project Entitlements using PAT token from

GET [https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.3)

But Project Entitlements are null.

PAT is of DevOps Owner account and it also has Project collection admin etc all rights.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `select=Projects` query parameter in the url to retrieve the Project Entitlements in the results. See below:

`https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/userentitlements?select=Projects&api-version=6.1-preview.3`

See more url parameters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/search%20user%20entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#uri-parameters).

Comment: I tried adding select option but still didn't worked.

Comment: @SenChavda It worked fine for my test.  Please check if the PAT was assigned read `Member Entitlement Management` scope.